# Select All checkbox by Javascript or console

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dom-events

I am having 100 Checkboxes on my web page. For testing purposes I want to tick all those boxes, but manually clicking is time consuming. Is there a possible way to get them ticked?

Perhaps a JavaScript or Chrome Console window, anything?

Comment: A bookmarklet in pure JS maybe?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I am unaware of what it is ? Could you please explain ?

Comment: 7 answers.. as I expected, there's enough explanations here :P Anyway, I submitted my own answer with detailed explanation/instructions.

Comment: Most probably it is for the field level permissions in salesforce.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The most direct way would be to grab all your inputs, filter just the checkboxes out, and set the checked property.

```
var allInputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++){
    if (allInputs[i].type === 'checkbox')
        allInputs[i].checked = true;
}
```

---

If you happen to be using jQuery—and I'm not saying you should start just to tick all your checkboxes for testing—you could simply do

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked", true);
```

or as Fabricio points out:

```
$(":checkbox").prop("checked", true);
```

Comment: [`$(':checkbox')`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/) is a handy shorthand for `$("[type='checkbox']")` as well.

Comment: @Derek- you're right - that's why I gave the pure JS answer first :)

Comment: Use crunchinator to convert the code above to a bookmarklet (unfortunately the 'let doesn't work with frames, fortunately Firefox can "Show only this frame"): [Bookmarklet Crunchinator](http://ted.mielczarek.org/code/mozilla/bookmarklet.html)

Comment: You can use javascript: <code> and jam it into the address bar and hit return and it works perfectly!

Answer (score 17):

Pure JS method, don't use jQuery.. its just silly for something so trivial.

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){
       el.checked=true;
     }
);​
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pfR3Z/)**

To use it on any webpage you can paste this into the address bar

```
javascript:[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){el.checked=true});
```

then drag that to your bookmarks, and you have a bookmarklet. Just click it whenever you need to use it on a page.

Comment: +1: Notes: Used functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call. Compatibility notice: `forEach` isn't implemented until version 9 in IE, `document.querySelectorAll` was implemented in version 8.

Comment: @Zeta yeah wont work in IE<8, but I chose `forEach` because he mentioned the chrome console, so I assume hes using a modern browser.

Comment: @Loktar: strange to read 'don't use jQuery.. its just silly for something so trivial.' isn't it?

Comment: @Talha not sure what you mean? But jQuery is crazy overkill for something like this. No need to include 2000 lines of code to check some check boxes.

Comment: @Loktar How can I check only one specific checkbox from a selection of many? The code line looks like `<input class="type" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: checked, value: id" value="1">` (there are many more checkboxes with higher values from 2 to 13.)

Answer (score 7):

`querySelectorAll` is your best choice here if you don't want jQuery!

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
    ele[i].checked = true;
}
//Done.
```

Answer (score 5):

by using [jquery](http://jquery.com/), simple as that

```
$('input:checkbox').each(function () {
   // alert(this);
   $(this).attr('checked', true);
  });
```

Or simply use

```
$('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);// use the property
```

OR

```
 $('input:checkbox').attr('checked', true); // by using the attribute
```

Comment: I find using Chrome console, .prop('checked', true) visibly turns on the checkbox.  .attr('checked', true) does not.  I don't understand, as .attr is much more often suggested but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Just paste one of these one-liners to your browser console:

**Tick** all checkboxes:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(e => e.checked = true);
```

**Untick** all checkboxes:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(e => e.checked = false);
```

Answer (score 2):

This JS code will check all checkboxed in your page:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    a[i].checked = true;​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/74Bzc/1/)

All you have to do then is create a bookmarklet with it, say, with [this bookmarklet maker](http://userjs.up.seesaa.net/js/bookmarklet.html), which generates this bookmarklet code:

```
javascript:var a=document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)a[i].checked=true;%E2%80%8B
```

Just add this URI to a bookmark in your bookmark toolbar, then all you have to do is click it whenever you need all the checkboxes in your page to be checked. =]

Answer (score 2):

#### Multiple Check All & Uncheck All Boxes

All You Need to change is the tag 'name' to change the what its turing ON/OFF

```
<FORM>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item0[]" onclick="CheckAll(this)" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item0[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item0[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item0[]" value="3" />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1[]" onclick="CheckAll(this)" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1[]" value="a" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1[]" value="b" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item1[]" value="c" />
    <br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" onclick="CheckAll(this)" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="a1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="b2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="item2" value="bc" />
</FORM>

<script>
    function CheckAll(x)
    {
        var allInputs = document.getElementsByName(x.name);
        for (var i = 0, max = allInputs.length; i < max; i++) 
        {
            if (allInputs[i].type == 'checkbox')
            if (x.checked == true)
                allInputs[i].checked = true;
            else
                allInputs[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

I provided answer to this question at Check all [Checkboxes in Page via Developer Tools](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43482111/30038)

In short you can do it from dev tools console (F12) by:

```
$$('input').map(i => i.checked = true)
```

or

```
$$('input[type="checkbox"').map(i => i.checked = true)
```

Comment: The best answer, but I had to use the click method to make this work: `$$('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(i => { if (!i.checked) i.click() } )`

Answer (score 0):

The following code will toggle all checkboxes. I think this is useful in case you want that feature. If you check a box it will uncheck that box. I know this doesn't answer the question technically but I wanted to put it up here because it's what I use. Thanks for the comment. I hope this answer is better suited to your pallette.

```
//Select All Checkboxes On Page
allSelects = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
for(i=0;i<allSelects.length;i++){
  allSelects[i].click();
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
  function selectAll(elem)
  {
  for (i = 0; i < elem.length; i++)
    elem[i].checked = true ;
  }
```

On Click of a button call this method and pass the name of the element(checkboxes-they all should be same named).

Comment: We want this to be done using console tab of any browser not using any button call.

Comment: @DadhichSourav, As per the stated question there is "or" in your query. Which means any way to do it (Anything).