# Check all Checkboxes in Page via Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, checkbox, google-chrome-devtools

I have a loop that creates 20 ***check-boxes*** in the same page (it creates different forms). I want via ***chrome developer tools*** to run a JavaScript without the use of any library that ***CHECK*** all *check-boxes* at the same time.

### This is as far as I got:

```
function() {
    var aa= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
     aa.elements[i].checked = checked;
    }
}
```

PS: I have searched and found a lot of Questions in Stack-Overflow but none worked for me, I'll be glad if someone could find me the correct answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select All checkbox by javascript or console](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908212/select-all-checkbox-by-javascript-or-console)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
(function() {
    var aa= document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
        if (aa[i].type == 'checkbox')
            aa[i].checked = true;
    }
})()
```

With up to date browsers can use [document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)

```
(function() {
    var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        aa[i].checked = true;
    }
})()
```

Comment: This just saved me having to check a million unsubscribe boxes. Thank you.

Comment: This just got me Udemy certificates in seconds. Thank You

Comment: This doesn't work on docs.google.com, maybe because it's made with Angular?

Answer (score 19):

From Console Dev Tools (F12) you can use query selector as you use in javascript or jQuery code.

'$$' - means select all items. If you use '$' instead you will get only first item.

So in order to select all checkboxes you can do following

`$$('input').map(i => i.checked = true)`

or

`$$('input[type="checkbox"').map(i => i.checked = true)`

Answer (score 8):

To modify the accepted answer slightly, if you're trying to check all of the boxes on some services, such as Loom.com, then you'll need to click each one instead of just setting them to "checked" status, otherwise the functionality doesn't work as expected.

Here's the code to do that:

```
(function() {
    var aa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
    for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++){
        aa[i].click();
    }
})()
```

Please note that longer lists of checkboxes will cause the page to pause temporarily as all checkboxes get automatically clicked for you.

Comment: Your suggestion is the .click() feature right? Amazing I needed this in the past.

Comment: That's awesome, everyone needs to know basic difference between `checked` and `click`

Answer (score 3):

You have it nearly correct. Just use

```
aa[i].checked = "checked";
```

inside the loop.

Namely, you need to make sure that:

1. `"checked"` is a string, not a variable identifier, and
2. you index directly on `aa`, not `aa.elements`, which does not exist

Answer (score 3):

Or, we could use this one line statement:

```
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]").forEach(element => element.checked = true);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're here for the quick one-liner:

```
var aa = document.getElementsByTagName("input"); for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) aa[i].checked = true;
```

Comment: This wasn't working for me. Adapted to the following, which does work: `var aa = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]'); for (var i = 0; i < aa.length; i++) aa[i].checked = true;`

Comment: @Tom Thanks! I skipped caring about only checkboxes but that could be put back in (the if statement from the main answer). I wonder what wasn't working for you... your solution might not help me on ancient IE versions. http://quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t12

Comment: @Tom FYI, I checked in again and it seems to be fine. https://jsfiddle.net/r7jnxta2/

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a one-liner without creating and calling an anonymous function. Use `querySelectorAll` to find the checkboxes, then loop through them with `for..of`.

Pasting the following line into the developer tools console achieves the desired result, assuming all the checkboxes are `input` tags with `type=checkbox`.

```
for (cb of document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]")) {cb.checked=true;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :)

```
(function () {
    var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

    //convert nodelist to array
    checkboxes = Array.prototype.slice.call(checkboxes);
    checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
        console.log(checkbox);
        checkbox.setAttribute('checked', true);
    });

})()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YxUHw/

Comment: You don't need to convert the nodelist to an array just call forEach the same way you called slice `    Array.prototype.forEach.call(checkboxes,function (checkbox) {
` http://jsfiddle.net/YxUHw/17/

Answer (score 1):

#### Javascript function to toggle (check/uncheck) all checkbox.

```
function checkAll(bx)
{
 var cbs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
 for(var i=0; i < cbs.length; i++)
 {
    if(cbs[i].type == 'checkbox')
    {
        cbs[i].checked = bx.checked;
     }
 }
}
```

If you want to it from developer tools then remove parameter of function and put the value as **"true"** or **"false"** instead of **"bx.checked"**

Answer (score 0):

Try [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute).

```
(function() {
  var aa = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i =0; i < aa.length; i++){
    aa.elements[i].setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  }
})();
```

Edit: added parens to execute the function immediately.

Comment: The code in your question creates a function: "function(){...}".  It doesn't actually _call_ the function though, that's why none of the answers provided here work for you.  We all assumed you wanted help with the internals of the function, not how to run it.  I've added parentheses to my solution so that it'll actually invoke the function immediately.