# How to Select All Checkboxes on YouTube?

Tags: google-chrome, checkbox, youtube, console

I'm trying to select all the videos for Khan Academy's YouTube fundraiser page:

[YouTube Fundraiser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qw9W8.png)

Unfortunately, we have thousands of videos and there's no Select All button to choose everything in our library.

As such, I'm looking for some way to select all the checkboxes on the page without having to click them one-by-one.

I've tried the other Stack Overflow recommendations for using the Chrome DevTools Console to Select All but they've all failed. I believe it's because YouTube isn't using standard checkboxes but instead this kind of code:

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; user-select: auto;">
<g style="user-select: auto;" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon">
<path d="M19 5v14H5V5h14m0-2H5c-1.1 0-2 .9-2 2v14c0 1.1.9 2 2 2h14c1.1 0 2-.9 2-2V5c0-1.1-.9-2-2-2z" style="user-select: auto;" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon">
</path>
</g>
</svg>
```

That said, any other recommendations for how to quickly Select All?

Thanks so much!

Comment: `I've tried the other Stack Overflow recommendations for using the Chrome DevTools Console to Select All but they've all failed.` - please share what did you tried.

Comment: @MarcoAurelioFernandezReyes Thanks for your kind reply!

I tried all of the variations suggested on this popular thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14245769/check-all-checkboxes-in-page-via-developer-tools

But none seemed to work - perhaps because YouTube's checkboxes aren't real checkboxes but images?