# Google chrome select All checkbox by Javascript or console

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, checkbox, dom-events

I am on the following google chrome page: `chrome://history/?q=a`

I have a list of results, I would like to make sure that through the browser console to select all checkboxes.

I've tried these ways, taking a cue from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10908269/8024296), but it doesn't seem to work:

```js
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]'),function(el){
       el.checked=true;
     }
);
```

```js
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll('cr-checkbox#checkbox.no-label'),function(el){
       el.checked=true;
     }
);
```

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: hard to replicate, as I got no checkboxes on that list

Comment: @FlashThunder: Do you use google chrome as a browser?

Comment: yes, but it's only a list (ul), no checkboxes in there, are you using some old version of Chrome?

Comment: @FlashThunder: I put a picture you don't see such a thing, with with a checkbox on the left.

Comment: check my not-answer

Comment: edited my not-an-answer

Comment: If you want to bulk-delete history items, just press Ctrl + A ( or CMD + A if you are on Mac) so that those all are selected. Then click on the delete button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This page is using web components with shadow DOM to isolate them. You'll need to go through each shadow root level:

```
document.querySelector('history-app')
        .shadowRoot.querySelector('history-list')
        .shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('history-item')
        .forEach(item => {
          item.shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-checkbox').click();
        });
```

Note that the page also implements *infinite-scroll* which means that only a couple of elements are displayed at first, and more are added as you scroll. This script will of course only select the ones that exist at the time you're running it.

Comment: The code seems to work but if I have 150 items displayed, it only selects 40 when I run the code.

Comment: I added a note in my answer. TLDR; Scroll all the way down before running the script

Comment: I did, but always 40 selects.

Comment: The page seems to be obtimized, they remove elements which are out of the viewport. Then you'll need to create a script which selects the 40 that exist, does the action you want to do, and repeats itself until there are no more elements left.

Comment: it's the first time I've heard of shadow dom.

Comment: A strange thing happens, I only have seven items found.
When I run the code it tells me that 41 items have been selected.

Answer (score 0):

I have a really nice one. Just scroll to the bottom of the History container and run this
Will select them all and delete them real quick
Might have to do it a couple of times when the page loads more results :)

```
document.querySelector('history-app')
        .shadowRoot.querySelector('history-list')
        .shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('history-item')
        .forEach(item => {
          item.shadowRoot.querySelector('cr-checkbox').click();
        });
document.querySelector("#history-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#toolbar").shadowRoot.querySelector("cr-toolbar-selection-overlay").shadowRoot.querySelector("#delete").click()
document.querySelector("#history-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#history").shadowRoot.querySelector("cr-dialog > div:nth-child(3) > cr-button.action-button").click()
```

This one selects all the checkboxes on the screen and deletes them
You will just have to go into the console and press up the whole time to clear the list
Can be improved, but this works really well as is